# Low footprint queue/messaging solution with persistant messages/overflow to disk

Tags: asynchronous, queue, jms, messaging

I need to build a highly scalable system to capture click traffic. I want the data to be processed asynchronously so the HTTP click request can return quickly. The click traffic needs to make its way to a datastore for reporting, but it doesn't need to be realtime. I want to be able to scale this solution by adding app servers, as many as needed to meet demand, fronted by a load balancer (probably Amazon's elastic load balancer). I've thought of a few possibilities (BTW the platform is Java):

1. Write click data to a memory queue (e.g. BlockingQueue). Another thread would drain the queue and insert into the backend datastore. This approach limits the queue size to available memory and if the node crashes all data on the queue is lost. I searched for a BlockingQueue implementation that overflows to disk when the queue reaches a certain size but didn't find anything.
2. Write click data to the filesystem on each node, with files of 100MB or so. The data would then be collected by a backend process and inserted into a datastore. With this approach there is no single point of failure and low chance of data loss. For example, if a node experiences errors it will be removed from the load balancer. If the backend datastore becomes unavailable, it can resume transferring data files when it's available again. Getting the data into the backend datastore would take some time but as long as all the data gets there, it's acceptable.
3. Use a messaging system, e.g. activemq or rabbitmq. A messaging system would introduce a single point of failure, unless installed on each node, which seems like overkill. A messaging system would provide durable messages and some guarantees that the messages are consumed exactly once, with transactions. A consumer of the queue would load the data into the datastore. The messaging system could be clustered in the backend but would need to server n-app servers and it could become the limiting factor in the system, affecting the http request performance.

Answer (score 1):

[Akka.io](http://akka.io/) sounds like a good framework for this task. It uses the actor model, and supports remote actors. This means that it guarantees that each message is consumed exactly once, and allows you to scale the system across multiple servers. It also supports file-based actor mailboxes and actor-supervision, so that if one server crashes the system can recover, and unprocessed messages are not lost. There are a lot of companies that use it professionally, so it has been pretty thoroughly battle tested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this might work with the file-based durable mailbox and how it can be deployed as a library instead of a server. I'm looking into it more.

Comment: I evaluated Akka and in doing so learned that its durable maibox does not behave as a durable queue. Essentially you can't decouple the mailbox from the consumer, so if you stop the consumer (Actor), the mailbox dies. Additionally the actorRef still accepts messages to the dead queue. This is unfortunate since it looked promising otherwise.